# Align a TextBlock and image in top of screen - uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to place an image at top left of screen. and a TextBlock at center of same line as image placed. Means at the top of screen there should be an image at left and a TextBlock at center. I tried like below. But both image and TextBlock are seems to be aligned at center.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="AliceBlue" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image x:Name="icon_goback2" Source="Assets/icon_home.png" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="50" Width="50" />
    <TextBlock Text="Your Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="70" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `Grid` and set `HorizontalAlignment` as `Left` and `Center` for `Image` and `TextBlock` respectively

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Well this is exactly the same answer as the one i posted above and before yours. A bit butt-hurt for sure, even if this problem was real simple. XD

Comment: @AndréB The problem with your answer is, you are using `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` (if you use `StackPanel` then you want to set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch`) and you want to set `VerticalAlignment` to `Center` to set `TextBlock` in center of the `Image`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="icon_goback2" Source="Assets/icon_home.png" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="50" Width="50"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Your Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="70"/>
</Grid>
```

What this code will do is divide your grid into 3 Columns and place the `<Image>` in the 1<sup>st</sup> Column (`Grid.Column="0"`) and `<TextBlock>` in the 2<sup>nd</sup> Column (`Grid.Column="1"`). You can additionally change the alignment of Image and Texblock if you need to.

Also, it is good to note that `StackPanel` will always override the Horizontal alignment of the Child elements when you are setting its orientation as horizontal. This is the reason why using a grid and dividing it into multiple rows and columns is better in scenarios like this.

---

**Edit :**
Since you have quite a large textblock you can change the column definitions to something like this :

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>        
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This will divide your grid into 2 parts with the column widths set automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi works fine.But text of my textblock is quite large.it is not shown fully in it

Comment: @nsds in that case you have to defined the second <ColumnDefinition> with an Auto Width